# Lambda syntax issues while testing

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Running the BeautifulSoup test to ensure installed correctly and receiving a syntax error relating to this line:

```
    strainer = SoupStrainer(text=_lambda(x):x[8]=='3')
```

Comment: what is this syntax? Try `text=lambda x: x[8]=='3'` ?

Comment: Is your syntax error being displayed when you try to run the code, or are you saying that this is valid code that executes as expected but that Sublime highlights it wrong? If it's the former, this is not a Sublime problem.